# Driving Toronto To Vancouver through the states, places to stay/see

Tags: usa, driving, canada, toronto, vancouver

I am planning to drive from Toronto to Vancouver through the states (I have done this once through Canada) I was just wondering if anyone can recommend places to visit/stay/eat (plan on seeing mt.rushmoore) Most likely taking the I-90w most of the way. Cheaper the better. We are planning a quick drive 4-6 nights depending on how good the attractions are.

Any other advice would be great!

Comment: I was recommended to drive through Manitoba and Saskatchewan. Because everybody should spend 24 straight hours driving through a wheat field once in their lives.

Comment: @DJClayworth it is certainly possible to spend 24 hours driving through a wheat field in the US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I havent' done it myself, but a friend of mine that I know used to do long haul in that stretch of the country, so I'll relay his findings

Chicago has to be a stop on your journey, especially if youre' a sports fan. Being the only four sports town on your route outside of Detroit, there's guarenteed to be a game playing whenever you decide to drive through. And the cuisine? Deliciso! Stopping by [Giordanos's](http://www.giordanos.com/) should be on your itinerary, for starters. Pretty much you coudl book a whole day or two and it wouldn't be wasted in the Windy City.

Also heard good things about Seattle. The sports scene is decent (I'm told the new park that the Mariners have is leagues ahead of the Kingdome), and there's a reason why they're known for coffee.

There's also Yellowstone Park if you're into that sort of thing. It's a nice break from the road, and is about an hour or so off the I-90 near Bozeman.

Outside of those and Mount Rushmore though, there's not a heck of a lot to see or do between Chicago and Seattle. It's just miles and miles of prairie and then mountains, which are great for viewing, but if you're' going after November lose their appeal quick when the snows hit.

Comment: Badlands National Park (and Wall Drug) alone are worth the visit!

Comment: The Battle of Little Bighorn National Monument is just west of Mount Rushmore on I-90.  As long as there isn't snow on the ground, it is a neat site!

Answer (score 7):

90W? Ug - that's multiple days of straight-line, boring driving. Interstates were built with getting from here to there in the shortest possible time, so they're built in the most boring parts of the country.

My advice - I'd recommend going from TO

- up to the Bruce Peninsula,
- take the [Chi-CheeMaun](http://www.chicheemaun.com/chi/english/index.html) ferry
- go north around Lake Superior
- get down to Fargo MN, then get on 94W from there.

94W has a number of smaller roads nearby that are going your direction and are a lot more scenic than the interstate. I was coming east and found 200 which intersects I94 at Glendive to be a really nice (motorcycle) ride - lots of variance in terrain, etc. Taking 200 from Glendive will also take you to Great Falls, then get on 89 towards Glacier National Park.

Lots of good stuff to see in that area if you have time!

One gotcha in the midwest is that towns are few and far between, so plan you fuel, food, and rest stops accordingly!

Comment: Fargo is in North Dakota.  The Minnesota side of the border is called Moorhead.

Answer (score 2):

[The Little Bighorn Battlefield National Monument](https://www.nps.gov/libi/index.htm), the site of Custer's Last Stand, is in Montana.  It is off I-90, a highway that passes through Chicago, and continues to Seattle; this is the same highway that goes past Mount Rushmore.

Comment: I-90 starts in Boston, continues to Buffalo, and skirts the Great Lakes to northern Ohio, where it joins I-80.  The two run together to northwest Indiana, where they split, and 90 continues through Chicago to Rockford and Madison before continuing west.  I-94 on the other hand passes near Milwaukee, but does not start there.  It starts in Port Huron, Michigan, and makes a similar detour around Lake Michigan to get to Milwaukee.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, I have modified my answer appropriately.  I confused the two highways.